# Crop image at the edge of the screen html

Tags: html, css, image

I want to cut the edge off my image when the image is to large to fit the screen.

When the screen is wide enough to fit the image

[image]

This happens when the screen is too small
[image]

I would like to cut the image at the edge of the screen/red line. If i set the max-width to 100% it just squeezes the image together. Here is the code for the image:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="ptable.PNG" style="height:400px;width: auto;margin: auto;float: left;">
</div>
```

Comment: You can make the image responsive, so that it will always be the same width as the container by adding `#container img { width: 100%; height: auto; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just add `overflow:hidden` to your container and it'll stop the image from going past it.

Comment: .container {
    overflow: hidden;
}                                                                   I added this to the stylesheet. it seems that the container rezises to fit the image, even i i do somthing like: width:100px;

Comment: @MadsAnkerNielsen container is an id, not class -> `#container`

Comment: Ohh my bad ;). Fixed it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the overflow CSS-attribute.

```
.container {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

or

```
<div id="container" style="overflow: hidden">
```

For more information see: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp